# flutter AndroidManifest warning - current min is 1

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, android-manifest, android-min-sdk

*AndroidManifest.xml* file gives warnings -

```
Attribute hardwareAccelerated is only used in API level 11 and higher(current min is 1)
Attribute windowSoftInputMode is only used in API level 3 and higher(current min is 1)
```

And

```
Should set android:versionCode to specify the application version
Should set android:versionName to specify the application version
```

Also

```
App is not indexable by Google Search;
```

While the app/build.gradle file reads -

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger() // 1
versionName flutterVersionName // '1.0'
```

The warnings started occurring recently without any new upgrades. My older flutter projects never encountered these warnings and are still working fine.

**Things I've tried:**

1. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.... > Invalidate And Restart
2. Just Restart
3. Create a different project from start

What resolves the warnings:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
 android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
```

Using the `<uses-sdk.../>` in *AndroidManifest.xml* resolves the warning(current min is 1) but hence invalidating the use of *app/build.gradle* file. Any suggestions please?

*I'm working on Android Studio 3.2.1*

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

use these commands to clean and fix plugins.

```
$ flutter clean
$ flutter pub cache repair
```

app/build.gradle :

```
android {
    namespace 'com.akbon.app' / add your package name
    compileSdk 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.akbon.app" / add your package name
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
//
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    tools:targetApi="33" 
//
```